# How to dismiss a whole stack of view controllers in navigation view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have two navigation view controllers.When I click on a button in a ViewController that belongs to the second navigation controller i want to dismiss the complete view controller stack of that navigation controller and want to go to a view controller in the first navigation controller.How can I do this? I tried `[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` and nothing seems to happen.How to do this ?

Comment: why do you have two navigation controllers? how are they related to each other?

Comment: I think you can just set self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[]  and then push what jut need. I don't know if you want animations.

Comment: @AndréSlotta They are not related to each other

Comment: @TomCobo No I dont want to push again i want to dismiss the whole view controllers

Comment: you can reach the root viewcontroller using popToRootViewController but dismissing the navigation is not available

Comment: @ColeXia the view controller i want to show belongs to different navigation stack

Comment: @ColeXia So I have to push that view conroller??

Comment: @ZeenathYousuff 1. push to that view controller (but it is separate I mean not included with the other navigation) 2. present the other navigation on current navigation.

Comment: if you are pushing the secondView controller do this, self.navigationController?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug must be somewhere else. The code you described you are using does indeed work. I created a new project and made an extremely simple example:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
- (instancetype)initWithColor:(UIColor *)color;
@end


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self presentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[MyViewController alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor redColor]]] animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end



@implementation MyViewController

- (instancetype)initWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = color;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint point = [touches.anyObject locationInView:nil];
    if(point.x < self.view.frame.size.width*0.5 && point.y < self.view.frame.size.width*0.5) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[MyViewController alloc] initWithColor:self.view.backgroundColor] animated:YES];
    } else if(point.x > self.view.frame.size.width*0.5 && point.y < self.view.frame.size.width*0.5) {
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[MyViewController alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]]] animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else if(point.x < self.view.frame.size.width*0.5 && point.y > self.view.frame.size.width*0.5) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
    } else if(point.x > self.view.frame.size.width*0.5 && point.y > self.view.frame.size.width*0.5) {
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

@end
```

If you copy this into a new project where `ViewController` is your main view controller a navigation controller will be created and presented on view did appear. The background will be red.

By pressing the top-left part of the screen a new controller of the same color will be pushed to the current top navigation controller.

By pressing top right a new navigation controller will be presented with a green view controller.

By pressing bottom left you may pop the current view controller if any.

And by pressing bottom right you will dismiss the top navigation controller.

So your case is pressing top-left a few times to generate a stack of view controllers on a single navigation controller. Then press top right to present yet another navigation controller (green one). Press a few times on top left to create a stack of few view controllers on a green navigation controller. Now press the bottom right to dismiss the whole green stack and be back to the red navigation controller stack.

Check your code a bit more to see what is going on in your case, why you are experiencing issues in your case. First check if `self.navigationController` is nil.

Answer (score -2):

try this i think it works for you

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: are you seen this in question `I have two navigation view controllers`

Comment: Mitul , No this will not work because  the view controller I want to show is in another navigation view controller.

Comment: let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "storyboardname", bundle: nil)
        mainNavVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navigationcontrollername") as! UINavigationController
        mainNavVC.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        
  mainNavVC.setViewControllers([viewcontrollername], animated: true)  
  self.window?.rootViewController = mainNavVC